# How can i add child items / subitems to my RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Actually i'm trying to make an app that will permise to take orders in a restaurant.

I have yet a recyclerView with different type of food and other stuff that you can find in a restaurant and another recyclerView that works like a notebook in which i put selected food's.

Now i would be able to add the variant, like i'm adding a PIZZA to my notebook and i would be able to add a variant like WITH PEPERONI and LARGE for variant's i've made an alertDialog with another recyclerView with also clickable items.

But now i would be able to add something like subitems (variant in this case) to my main item PIZZA choosen from my variant recyclerView any suggestion on how can i do it?

Here is an example of my activity with the food recyclerView the notebook recyclerView and the alertDialog with variant recyclerView

[image]

And here is a fantastic drawing of what i would to archive

[image]

PS: i've found solutions like expandable recyclerView but it's not what i'm looking for, the variants should be in a different ArrayList and have to be ever visible if exist.

Here is what i'm trying to archive ( this was a lot bugged stuff i've made )

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer to the question.

You can try this library: 
[ExpadablRecyclerview](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view)

Or you can try one of these tutorials
[Tutorial 1](https://android.jlelse.eu/get-expandable-recyclerview-in-a-simple-way-8946046b4573), [Tutorial 2](https://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/)

Comment: that's greate but i'm having some issues with adding child can you help me?

Comment: What problem did you meet?

Comment: i used tuto1 for doing it but how can i add by clicking a recyclerView to add just parent and if i click items from another recyclerView add child to last parent ?

Comment: sorry but I do not understand very well. what result do you want?

Comment: Look at the 1st screen, i want that if i click an item from the bottom recyclerView it's going to be added to the top recyclerView as you can see in 1st screen part 2, and if i press on button "VARIANTI" that open alertDialog with another recyclerView 1st screen part 3 i want that the clicked item from it will be added as child to the last item from the 1st screen part 2.

Comment: I've added a screen what i archived but it doesn't work's properly

Answer (score 0):

```
create a model class with title and Arraylist<String>
and PASS Arraylist<model> to the main adapter .
title shows name like pizza and arraylist<String> will be subcatgories.

my suggestion would be add recyclerview as item inside the mainrecycleview.
such as
recyclerview should be below textview showing title 

the recyclerview should be hidden also should put a margin to see a sub category

and when sub datas are added add data to this recyclerview using positon also make it visible and call notifydatachange .

if arraylist<String> is not empty make item recyclerview visble and show values

its not easy but a suggestion you can try if you dont get an easy method.
```

Answer (score -1):

Each item layout of ParentRecyclerView should contains a ChildRecyclerView, then `ChildRecycler.setAdapter(ChildAdapter)` in ParentAdapter 's OnCreateViewHolder()